# PHP - What is the best hash algorithm to calculate the similarity between two string?

Tags: php, string, algorithm, hash, similarity

I want to use [hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) to calculate/find the similarity between two strings.

In PHP there are many supported hashing algorithms. List can be obtain with [hash_algos(](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php)).

Which is the best recommended algorithm to use for?

Comment: how do you define "best recommended algorithm", most fast or most secure ... or most precise ?

Comment: If those are just strings, i would certainly use:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php
If you want to know 2 strings are exactly the same, use:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest most fast.

Comment: @Viktor Koncsek The complexity of the levenshtein algorithm is O(m*n), where n and m are the length of string to compare. It's why I use hash function.

Comment: More important than how you define "best" is how you define "similar." *What are you trying to do?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is too ambiguous.

Firstly, you say you want to calculate similarity between the two strings. This does not require hashing at all. You can just use `compare`, `equality`, `levenshtein distance`, `edit distance` etc. for that.

> Why do we use hashing

If there is some sensitive data which we cannot store in cleartext **and** we don't need to use the data in any processing, calculations or modify the data but only need to *compare it to exact equality*, we use hashing.
`eg. storing user passwords, which would need only comparison with the password string once he tries logging in`

> Parameters

Speed, security (and maybe, popularity)

A few of most popular hashes include `md5, SHA-1, SHA-256 and SHA-512`. This is the order of them being secure and relatively slow.

```
fast, less secure | md5 < SHA-1 < SHA-256 < SHA-512 | relatively slow, more secure
```

I would recommend using SHA-1 or SHA-256, which are fast enough and enough secure as well.

Also, use a secret salt to increase security manyfold (using salt while hashing increases security exponentially, for obvious reasons).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: He asked the recommended algo for hash...I gave him the names. How does this not answer the question? If you want some added details, I'll be happy to add.

Answer (score 3):

Hash has nothing to do with similarity. Moreover, majority of hashing algorithms produces results almost entirely different for extremely similar strings. For example SHA1 of:

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` = `2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12`

and the difference with one symbol is entirely different string:

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cog` = `de9f2c7fd25e1b3afad3e85a0bd17d9b100db4b3`

---

There are simple and well know algorithms for finding string similarities. [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) for strings of the same length, [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for different length string are just a few examples of [string metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric)

P.S. if you really really want to use hashing - the right term for this type of hashing is [locality preserving hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_preserving_hashing). You can read about it [here](https://www.fbi.h-da.de/fileadmin/gruppen/FG-IT-Sicherheit/Lectures/selected-topics-it-sec/vorlesung_it-sec_ss12_kap03_sphf.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out the [Nilsimsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilsimsa_Hash) algorithm for an introduction.

> "The goal of Nilsimsa is to generate a hash digest of an email message
> such that the digests of two similar messages are similar to each
> other"

There's a php package here([1](https://packagist.org/packages/opctim/php-nilsimsa),[2](https://github.com/opctim/php-nilsimsa))

There are references to stronger algorithms/lower false positive matches [TLSH](https://github.com/trendmicro/tlsh), [Ssdeep](https://ssdeep-project.github.io/ssdeep/index.html) and [Sdhash](https://github.com/sdhash/sdhash).